# Set initial value to select within custom component in Angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, angular-ngmodel

As you can see in this plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/3EDk5xxSLRolv2t9br84?p=preview) I have two selects: one in the main component behaving as usual, and one in a custom component, inheriting the ngModel settings.

The following code links the innerNgModel to the component ngModel.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  //First set the valueAccessor of the outerNgModel
  this.ngModel.valueAccessor = this.innerNgModel.valueAccessor;

  //Set the innerNgModel to the outerNgModel
  //This will copy all properties like validators, change-events etc.
  this.innerNgModel = this.ngModel;
}
```

It works, since the name property is updated by both selects.

However when it first loads the second select has no selection.

I guess I'm missing something, a way to initialize the innerNgModel with the initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird situation to do something like this, but I believe to get this working they need to implement another life-cycle hook. AfterModelSet or something like that :)

Anyways, you can solve this with a simple `setTimeout` and a `setValue`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.ngModel.valueAccessor = this.innerNgModel.valueAccessor;
   this.innerNgModel = this.ngModel;
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.innerNgModel.control.setValue(this.ngModel.model);
   })
}
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HXXFfBLORQNJa1LxWxhd?p=preview)